# How to use responsive page in bootstrap iframe using react code

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have an zoho Dashboard which works fine in both Desktop and Mobile device that means it is an responsive apps which has bootstrap feature.

I have call this Zoho Dashboard link in bootstrap "iframe".It works fine in desktop but this dashboard is not responsive in Mobile Device.Please check the below code and advise how to do this..

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ConfigItem from '../../Config';
import axios from 'axios';
class ZohoDashboard extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {url: ''};

    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.fetchData();
    }
    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
        if(prevProps.match.params.id !== this.props.match.params.id) {
            this.fetchData();
        }
    }
    fetchData = () => {

        axios.get(ConfigItem[0].APIPath+'Menus/'+this.props.match.params.id)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res.data.data[0].URL);
            this.setState({url:res.data.data[0].URL});
        }) 
    }

    render() {

        return (

            <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src={this.state.url} allowfullscreen></iframe> 
          </div>



        );
    }
}

export default ZohoDashboard;
```

Comment: can you share the `<meta name="viewport" ...>` tag from the index.html in your reach public folder?

Comment: Ref: *" that means it is an responsive apps which has bootstrap feature"*. Wrong! Just because the context page is responsive doesn't mean it uses Bootstrap. Also, what happens in an `<iframe>` can be considered a separate page (because that's what it actually is). It loads its own resources and if you want to make it responsive you need to use `@media` queries in it, either by using Bootstrap or any alternative.